# OSM Overpass missing data in query result

Tags: python, json, gis, openstreetmap

I'm gathering all cities, towns and villages of some countries from OSM using an Overpass query in a Python program.
Everything seems to be correct but I found a town in Luxembug that is missing im my result set. It concerns the town Kiischpelt.

'''
import requests
import json

```
Country = 'LU'

overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
overpass_query = """
[out:json];
area["ISO3166-1"=""" + Country + """][admin_level=2]->.search;
(node["place"="city"](area.search);
 node["place"="town"](area.search);
 node["place"="village"](area.search);
 way["place"="city"](area.search);
 way["place"="town"](area.search);
 way["place"="village"](area.search);
 rel["place"="city"](area.search);
 rel["place"="town"](area.search);
 rel["place"="village"](area.search);
 
);
out center;
"""
response = requests.get(overpass_url, 
                      params={'data': overpass_query})
data = response.json()

filename = """C:/Data/GetGeoData/data/""" + Country + 'cities' +'.json'
f = open(filename,'w', encoding="utf-8")
json.dump(data, f)
f.close()
```

'''

When searching on the OSM site for Kiischpelt, I get a result of type relation but it doesnet appear in my result set.
Also when I change the query as follows
'''rel"place";''' which should return all places of all kinds (city, town, village, isolated dwelling,...)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks!

Comment: It seems that there is no place called Kiischpelt in OSM. Only an [administrative boundary](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/details.html?osmtype=R&osmid=1357619).

Comment: So, rather a data issue than a query issue?

Comment: That depends, why do you expect Kiischpelt to be in your results? There is no town called Kiischpelt. It is just the name of a [commune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiischpelt).

Comment: By visiting a campsite in Kautenbach, I also got to know the community of Kiischpelt. While testing my dataset, I happened to use the name of this municipality.
According to wikipedia :
Kiischpelt is a municipality in the canton of Wiltz in Luxembourg. The municipality was created on 1 January 2006 by the merger of the former municipalities of Kautenbach and Wilwerwiltz. Kiischpelt has an area of 33.58 km².

So I would expect that this municipality also appears in OSM, right?

Comment: You can find it in OSM, but you'll have to change the query: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1axA. Municipal boundaries are [admin_level=8](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WikiProject_Luxembourg/Borders#Village_.2F_Town_Limitation_.28admin_level.3D8.29)